# Python module imports okay but it does not from a Screen window

Tags: python, module, pip

I have a python (3.7) script that runs okay from shell.
It has a line `from pcloud import PyCloud`
Running the same script from a new *screen* window I get

```
ImportError: No module named 'pcloud'
```

I already have installed

```
 sudo pip3.7 install picamera pillow screen
```

`screen --version`

> Screen version 4.05.00 (GNU) 10-Dec-16

What am I missing?

Comment: just check are you using the same python environment in both

Comment: In the regular window I run `python3 script.py` same as the Screen window where I get the error.  If I run `python3.7 script.py` it runs okay in both shells. It seems it runs an older, 3.5 python version. pyCloud works in versions >=3.6.  I had `echo "alias python3='/usr/local/bin/python3.7'"  >> ~/.profile` when I installed version 3.7. Isn't that enough to run python3=python3.7 in all windows?

Comment: if it works with `python3.7` then use `python3.7` instead of `python3`. You can even add `python3.7` in first like with shebang `#!` - like `/#!/usr/bin/env python3.7` -  and set it executable `chmod +x  script.py` and then you can run it as normal program without using `python3` or `python3.7` because it will get information from first line (shebang) to run code.

Comment: Maybe just create a virtual environment and work there, that way u keep track of your system python version and project python version

Comment: @furas I understand the solutions but I don't get why the behavior is different in both windows

Comment: And by the way I also get why at my question the line "ImportError: No module named 'pcloud'" was changed from blockquote to code sample.  It is not a code sample, it is a quoted output of a command

Comment: different windows may use different settings. I'm not sure if `screen` has to uses settings from `.profile` but on my Linux it loads `.bashrc`.  In both windows you could check `alias` and `env`

Comment: BTW: it may not be good to change `python3` from 3.6 to 3.7 because 3.6 may have modules which system may needs to run correctly. But if you want to change it then maybe remove original `python3` (which you can find with `which python3`) and create soft link `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python3`